# How to find if a word has standard ASCII characters?

Tags: delphi, unicode, character-encoding

I'm using Delphi Rio 10.3.2 and I need to understand if a string just has ASCII characters or not.

Also, if it does not contains just ASCII characters I need to understand if it's Cyrillic.

I was thinking about unicode ranges..so

this is Latin:

https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0020-007F

and this is Cyrillic:

https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF

But I do not know how to check for unicode ranges and also I don't know if it's a good way to achieve what I need.

Can anybody help?
Thank you.

Comment: The range is not sufficient to cover Cyrillic. Run `unichars '\p{ScriptExtensions=Cyrillic}'` to see the correct result for Unicode 12.1. Codepoint intspan replicated here for your convenience: `U+0400…U+052F,U+1C80…U+1C88,U+1D2B,U+1D78,U+2DE0…U+2DFF,U+2E43,U+A640…U+A69F,U+FE2E…U+FE2F`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step through the characters one by one and inspect their ordinal value. For example:

```
var
  c: char;
  str: string;
....
str := ...;
for c in str do
  if InRange(Ord(c), $0020, $007f) then
    // ASCII
```

Answer (score 1):

**TPerlRegEx** is your friend!

If you haven't used these before don't panic.

I just found [this 'SkillSprint'](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/skill-sprint-regular-expressions-and-tregex) for using these - I haven't watched it but it's probably helfult to you.

There are also lots of tools online to help you test your RegEx syntax to see if it works.  [This link](https://regex101.com/) goes to one I have used myself (there are lots available).

```pascal
function IsJustAscii(Input: String): Boolean
var
  pRegEx: TPerlRegEx;
begin
  pRegEx:=TPerlRegEx.Create;
  pegEx.RegEx:='^[\x20-\x7f]*$';           // Any number (including 0) of ascii characters 
  pRegEx.Subject:=Input;
  pRegEx.Options:=[preSingleLine, preMultiLine];
  Result:=pRegEx.Match;
  FreeAndNil(pRegEx);
end

function ContainsCyrillic(Input: String): Boolean
var
  pRegEx: TPerlRegEx;
begin
  pRegEx:=TPerlRegEx.Create;
  pegEx.RegEx:='[\x{0400}-\x{04ff}]+';    // one or more cyrillic characters
  pRegEx.Subject:=Input;
  pRegEx.Options:=[preSingleLine, preMultiLine];
  Result:=pRegEx.Match;
  FreeAndNil(pRegEx);
end
```

The first function checks that the whole string only includes Ascii characters (you may want to allow newlines, tabs, carriage return etc.)

The second function finds if there *any* Cyrillic characters in the string.